# Deployment error while using Spring Integration with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I had done a poc on SI in a spring boot application where I was able to send and receive mesages from TcpOutBoundGateway. Now I'm trying to merge my sample spring integration module to my actual enterprise spring application.

To do this, I added spring-integration.xml in the enterprise application and imported it in spring-core.xml

```
  <import resource="classpath:rx/spring-integration.xml" />
```

Also added, spring-integration-ip and spring-integration-core to build.gradle file.
In my service class, autowired my SI bean

```
<bean id="rxService" class="com.api.services.RxService"/>
```

which will create payload to be sent to gateway as well as receive the response and parse the result and return the model object. 
But on starting tomcat, I am getting the below error.

```
01/24 13:15:46:228  ERROR [ContextLoader.java:312] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildDetails': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'apiVersion' in value "${apiVersion}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'apiVersion' in value "${apiVersion}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:851)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
... 22 more
Jan 24, 2019 1:15:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildDetails': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'apiVersion' in value "${apiVersion}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'apiVersion' in value "${apiVersion}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:851)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
... 22 more
```

Here is my SI configuration, which is a request response model, where the client is my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration- 
ip.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder />

<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface=" com.api.rx.RxGateway"
    default-request-channel="objectOut" />

<int:channel id="objectOut" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="10.236.249.XX" port="9XXX" single-use="false"
    so-timeout="50000000" using-nio="false" so-keep-alive="true"
    serializer="customDSerializer" deserializer="customDSerializer" />

<bean id="customDSerializer" class="com.api.rx.CustomSerializerDeserializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="4096" />
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="objectOut" reply-channel="toSA" connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="10000000" reply-timeout="50000000" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
    ref="rxService" method="parseResponse" />

<bean id="rxService" class="com.api.services.RxService"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" />
<int:channel id="bytesIn" />
</beans>
```

FYI - We are using a common jar, which has a bean named buildDetails with a property - apiVersion. It's gradle multiflat project and the module I'm working on has a buildDetails.properties files which has a key-apiVersion and value.

Now the confusing part is - I get this deployment error only if I just import SI xml in spring-core.xml, don't even have to autowire its service bean.

It would be helpful if you could validate the steps I have done to integrate SI into my application is correct.

Comment: Can you show us how is your `buildDetails.properties` file loaded in your Spring config? Cause it seems like Spring is not seeing it somehow.

Comment: In Spring-web.xml,   `<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true"  location="classpath:application.properties,classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties,classpath:buildDetails.properties,classpath:swaggerDocumentation.properties" />`

Comment: Are the other properties from this file actually loaded? Can you try adding a leading slash : `classpath:/buildDetails.properties` instead? I remember having different behavior with or without this leading slash when property file comes from external lib.

Comment: You said the SI is imported from `spring-core.xml` but this comment says that placeholder config is in web.xml - the web context is a child of the root context; the root context can't see beans in the web context (but beans in the web context can see beans in the root context).

Comment: Why do you have a `property-placeholder` in that SI config? More over why it is empty? How about to remove it?

Comment: @Matt, It works fine if I comment the SI dependencies. I moved `<import resource="classpath:rx/spring-integration.xml"/> ` to spring-web.xml and got rid of the issue. But now it says, `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.heb.mpos.api.services.RxService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. `. when I try to Autowire rxService in OrderService class.

Comment: RxService class has 2 methods 1. buildAndSendPayload() 2. parseResponse() so that I can call orderService.buildAndSend to request gateway and direct reply channel to rxService bean, parseResponse method. I don't know if doing that is correct.

Comment: @Gary, We're using spring-core and spring-web.xml's apart from web.xml. Initially I imported spring-integration into spring-core and I faced the issue in question. Now I moved to spring-web and it is not getting thrown. But like I mentioned, the  NoSuchBeanDefinitionException is thrown when I autowire rxService which I had defined in SI config

Comment: @ArtemBilan Tried removing `property-placeholder` but still getting the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException `

Comment: Try moving the si back to the root, but also move the main property placeholder (the one with the properties) there too so it is available to both contexts.

Comment: I did and that resolved the issue. Thank you, @Gary! The buildDetails was declared in spring-web.xml. I moved it to spring-core and that worked. Also, I imported SI config in spring-core itself. So the cause, I believe is what Gary told about visibility issues when you declare beans in web and core. Thanks @ArtemBilan and Matt for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web context is a child of the root application context; if the properties are in the web context, beans in the root context can't use them.

Move the properties to the root context so they are visible to both.